# What syntax is acceptable for classifier + noun + adjectival phrase

Tags: syntax

I am wondering what the acceptable combinations of classifier, noun, and adjectival phrase are? For example 一本 + 有意思的 + 书

Is it acceptable to say both of the following?:

> - 一本有意思的书。
> - 有意思的一本书。

Are there any other ways to produce the same meaning?
What is the difference (if any) in the meaning / connotation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

有意思的一本书 is rarely used, either in colloquial language or formal speech.

However, 很有意思的一本书 is popular, as in "这是很有意思的一本书" (interchangeable with "这是一本很有意思的书" and "这本书很有意思"). The sentence literally means "this is a book that's very interesting".

I do not know why adding "很" makes it sound right. [The Google results](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=%E6%9C%89%E6%84%8F%E6%80%9D%E7%9A%84%E4%B8%80%E6%9C%AC%E4%B9%A6&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) are quite convincing, though: all of them have "很" before "有意思的一本书".

(Is it the same case with "你很漂亮" (correct) and "你漂亮" (incorrect) ?)

Comment: I know when you are writing a notice for a lost item, you invert the order of the MW and the noun, so you would say something like: "丢失了眼镜一副”

Comment: I think "丢了一副眼睛" sounds right, too. The only situation I can think of where you must invert the order is the idiom "小事一桩" (no big deal; a piece of cake).

Answer (score 1):

Both are valid and commonly used. They have the same meaning.

NOW:

for 一本 + 有意思的 + 书：

> - `一本有意思的书。` - GOOD, "An interesting book"
> - `有意思的一本书。` - GOOD, "An interesting book"
> - `有意思的书一本。` - WEIRD, and maybe incorrect grammar; don't use

situation suited for `adj. + 的`: `搞笑的(funny)`, `无聊的(boring)`, etc
for 一本 + 好 + 书：

> - `一本好书。` - GOOD, "A great book"
> - `好一本书。` - different meaning from the other 2 combinations, but totally valid; I'm unable to explain.
> - `好书一本。` - GOOD, "An awesome book!!", better than "A great book"

situation suited for selective one word adj.: `好`, `烂`, `破`, etc.

note that the second combination is *ONLY* valid for `好`.

Comment: interesting. I wonder why 有意思的书一本 sounds weird and 好书一本 doesn't?!?

Comment: If I change `好` to `精彩(exciting)`, `精彩书一本` or `精彩的书一本` still very *wired*, maybe because `好` is an one word adj. or maybe it's a magic word?

Comment: I've update my answer to include more one word example.

Comment: "好一本书" in your second example is similar to "what a *special* book it is" in English. "好" here helps to form an exclamatory sentence and does not mean "great". 好一个混蛋 = what a jerk; 好一句“不关我的事” = (roughly) how dare you say "it's none of my business"! We can start a new question, actually.

Answer (score 1):

Although both of them are valid, 一本有意思的书 is more commonly used than 有意思的一本书.

Actually, the usage is depend on the context.

For example, 这是一本有意思的书 is OK; 这是有意思的一本书 is also OK, but more emphasized on "有意思".

Another example, 昨天我看了一本有意思的书 is OK; 昨天我看了有意思的一本书 is NOT acceptable.

Another example, 我有一本有意思的书 is OK; 我有有意思的一本书 is NOT acceptable.